# How to Combine term query and numeric query using operators in Lucene.NET?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have tried the following methods to combine the query but I don't know how to add (AND,OR,NOT) operator in these query.

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("Skill_Summary", "Java"));
Query pageQueryRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("Experience", 1, 2, true, true);
booleanQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.Add(pageQueryRange, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
var hits = searcher.Search(booleanQuery);
```

The result of the above `booleanQuery` is `+Skill_Summary:Java +Experience:[1 TO 2]` still not getting the result

```
String termQueryString = "Skill_Summary:\"Java\"";
Query termQuery = queryParser.Parse(termQueryString);
Query QueryRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("Experience", 1, 3, true, true);
Query query = termQuery.Combine(new Query[] { termQuery, QueryRange });
var hits = searcher.Search(query);
```

Comment: What are your expected results vs. actual? BTW your query looks fine, though the 1st example uses range [1 TO 2] and the 2nd example uses [1 TO 3].

Comment: i need to use AND operator to join the two query (query1 and pageQueryRange) and get the desired output (eg:{Skill_Summary:Java AND Experience:[1 TO 2]}).

Comment: Actually `+Skill_Summary:Java +Experience:[1 TO 2]` is the same as `Skill_Summary:Java AND Experience:[1 TO 2]` as the `+` sign basically says both terms of the criteria need to `true`. Also, using a `TermQuery` will match the values literally, so it will *not* match "java" or "JAVA", which can be the issue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` functionality using Lucene.NET is to combine queries using the `BooleanQuery` class. When you add your queries to the booleanQuery you can use the `Occur` argument to specify how the query should be treated,

```
var termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Skill_Summary", "Java"));
var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

// Use 'Occur.MUST` to simulate an AND, or '+Skill_Summary:Java'
booleanQuery.Add(termQuery, Occur.MUST);

// Use 'Occur.SHOULD` to simulate an OR, or just 'Skill_Summary:Java'
booleanQuery.Add(termQuery, Occur.SHOULD);

// Use 'Occur.MUST_NOT` to simulate a NOT, or just '-Skill_Summary:Java'
booleanQuery.Add(termQuery, Occur.MUST_NOT);
```

In your example, you might find that the `TermQuery` tries to match the value literally, so it won't match values like "java" or "Java". To do that you will need to do,

```
var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

// Use QueryParser
var query1 = new QueryParser(version, "Skill_Summary", analyzer).Parse("Java");
var pageQueryRange = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("Experience", 1, 2, true, true);
booleanQuery.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.Add(pageQueryRange, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
var hits = searcher.Search(booleanQuery);
```

Comment: i got messed with termquery and queryparser.thank you for good explanation.Now it works like a charm.